# bad operand type string for unary operator '+'

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm currently working on a module class with several student objects and have been experiencing the following issue -

bad operand type string for unary operator '+'

I would appreciate any assistance, my code is as follows.

```
public class Module {
private String moduleTitle;
int percentageCoursework;
int percentageExam;
private Student studentsList[] = new Student[3];

public Module (String moduleTitle, int percentageCoursework, int percentageExam,String     studentOne, String studentTwo, String studentThree, String studentsTitles[])
{        
this.moduleTitle = moduleTitle;
this.percentageCoursework = percentageCoursework;
this.percentageExam = percentageExam;
this.studentsList[0].name = studentOne;
this.studentsList[1].name = studentTwo;
this.studentsList[2].name = studentThree;

}
            public void ShowDetails()
{
    System.out.println("moduleTitle : " + moduleTitle + 
            "\n percentageCoursework : " + percentageCoursework + 
            "\n percentageExam : " + percentageExam + 
            +studentsList[0].name+studentsList[1].name+studentsList[2].name);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    "\n percentageExam : " + percentageExam + 
    +studentsList[0].name+studentsList[1].name+studentsList[2].name);
//  ^
//  ^ look! oh noes!
```

There is an extra `+` in the beginning of the last line.

Comment: Thank you!  That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
percentageExam + +studentsList[0].name+studentsList[1].name

             //  ^^  Two "+" side by side.
```